# Ghcup installs stack as "stack-2.7.5.exe" and not "stack.exe" on windows

Tags: haskell, ghcup

I have windows 11 and I installed haskell using ghcup. Ghcup installed me a "2.7.5" version of stack, ang in `C:\ghcup\bin` it's named as `stack-2.7.5.exe` and not `stack.exe`. Why is that so? Shouldn't there at least be a wrapper that uses installed version?

Comment: This might not be the best place to get help with this. See the "Need help?" section at https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/.

Comment: That is because `ghcup` can  install different version of the same executable. Therefore, you can install `stack-2.7.5` and `stack-2.9.0` (for example). In theory, your PATH should point to one of them using the name `stack`. In linux-like system it uses a symbolic link, I don't know in windows. Can't you execute `stack` on a console?

Comment: What does the command `which stack` return on Linux? Or `get-command stack` on PowerShell?

Comment: @FrancisKing the relevant command on Windows is `WHERE`, so `WHERE STACK` (though PowerShell's `Get-Command` will also work if you're in PowerShell).